# Install mod_wsgi for python 3 in fedora 20

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, fedora

Does Feodora's mod_wsgi support python 3?

I can use virtualenv to build python 2 environment for mod_wsgi, and it works fine. But when I build the environment for python 3 the error log always says:

```
 ImportError: No module named site
```

I just use `WSGIPythonHome` point to `/path/to/py3venv`

How can I configure mod_wsgi for python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take a mod_wsgi compiled for one Python version and forcibly point it at a virtual environment for another Python version. The mod_wsgi binary must be compiled for the specific Python version you want to use.

In other words, you cannot force a mod_wsgi compiled for Python 2.X, to use a virtual environment for Python 3.X.

So, if your mod_wsgi is for Python 2.X, remove it and install the variant of the package for Python 3, or compile it yourself from source code.

Comment: thanks, so i should recompile it or wait official repo change it to py3?